# Problems allocating arrays when descendant of matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous

Tags: oop, matlab

Sorry about the formatting, i pasted and then applied the {} control but it still looks mangled. Please educate me if i'm misusing the tool somehow.

I have a base class:

```
classdef SystemNode < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous
    properties (Abstract)
       description 
       quantity
       parent 
       unit_cost
       learning_curve
       average_cost
       total_cost
       children
   end
end
```

I have a descendant:

```
classdef Subsystem < models.system.SystemNode
   properties
       description 
       quantity
       parent 
       children
       key
   end

   properties (Dependent)
       unit_cost
       learning_curve
       average_cost
       total_cost
   end

   methods
       function self = Subsystem(description, quantity, parent)
           % TODO: Validate Inputs
           self.description = description;
           self.quantity = quantity;
           self.parent = parent;
           self.children = [];
           self.key = char(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
       end

       function add_child(self, node)
           % TODO: Validate Inputs
           self.children = [self.children node];
       end

       function unit_cost = get.unit_cost(self)
           % Cost if there were only one.
           unit_cost = 0;
           for child = self.children
               unit_cost = child.unit_cost;
           end
           unit_cost = unit_cost*self.quantity;
       end

       function learning_curve = get.learning_curve(self)
           learning_curve = 0;



       end
```

I can't get .add_child() to work. 
for example:

```
>> ss = models.system.Subsystem('test', 1, []);
>> ss.add_child('a')
>> ss.children

ans =

     []
```

If i descendend my abstract class from handle instead of the Mixin this works fine. What am i doing wrong??

BTW. I am using Matlab 2011b

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `handle` that makes the object behave in a pass-by-reference manner. If you want this kind of behavior, try the following:

```
classdef SystemNode < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous & handle
```

If you do not inherit from `handle`, you get normal Matlab pass-by-value behavior. In this case, if you want to update the state of an object, you have to return the updated object from the setter method, and store the returned updated value.

So the setter has to return the updated self.

```
   function self = add_child(self, node)
       self.children = [self.children node];
   end
```

And calls to it store the returned updated object.

```
ss = ss.add_child('a')
```

If you don't store a new value in `ss`, you're still looking at the value of `ss` from before the `add_child` call, with no children.

Comment: Additionally, one could simply have ``SystemNode`` inherit from ``handle``